# Piranha CMS Http 404 Error for ASP.NET Web Pages website

Tags: asp.net, piranha-cms

I have recently added piranhacms ASP.NET Web Pages website to my existing website. I have created a new site and added new page under that. But i am getting 404 error while i am trying to preview the page.
Below is the detailed information

Detailed Error Information:

```
Module     __DynamicModule_Piranha.Web.ApplicationModule, Piranha, Version=2.2.5281.40282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null_e5ce85b1-41f4-43a3-a0a8-4e3b87dc4383
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      url/draft/event-information
Physical Path      C:\Users\Pankaj\Learning & Interview\testsite\draft\event-information
Logon Method       Forms
Logon User     60b397ae-5538-4c51-b199-de93ae79df2a
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\Pankaj\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\TESTSITE
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! Is it just the preview functionality that is not working, or can't you view it by visiting the external permalink either?

Answer (score 0):

The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link; hence the 404 error is one of the most recognizable errors users can find on the web.

so I guess u need to check the pysical path of the your files